# How can I sum the last 15 rows in my database table?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

I have a Sales table, with the following columns:

- employeeID
- amount
- date

Now I want to `SUM` up the last 15 rows, so I am currently doing:

```
SELECT TOP 15 SUM(amount) FROM Sales ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

But I get 15 rows obviously, is there a way I can sum it up and not have to loop through and SUM it on the client side?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUM (Amount)
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 15 amount FROM Sales ORDER BY [Date] DESC) foo
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Sum(amount )
FROM
(
   SELECT Top 15 amount FROM Sales ORDER BY [Date] Desc
) as bar
```